# Finding the limit as $n \to \infty $ of $n\ln\left(1+\frac{\ x}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms, indeterminate-forms

Find

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{\ x}{n^2}\right)$$

My attempt: $\lim_{n\to \infty} n \left[\ln\left(\frac{\ n^2 +x}{n^2}\right)\right]$

= $\lim_{n\to \infty} n [\ln (n^2 +x) - \ln(n^2)]$

But I'm not sure how to get this out of indeterminate form.

Comment: Assume $n$ is large and use Taylor series for $\log(1+y)$ when $y$ is small. Later, replace $y$ by $\frac x{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x>0$. One may use
$$
0<\ln(1+u)<u,\quad u \in (0,1),
$$ giving, as $ n \to \infty$,
$$
0<n\ln \left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)<\frac{x}{n}
$$ and conclude.

Comment: I understand, thank you!

Comment: @Ella You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$n\ln\left(1+\frac{\ x}{n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{n}n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{\ x}{n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( \left( 1+\frac{x}{n^2} \right)^{n^2} \right)$

If $n\to\infty$, then $ \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( \left( 1+\frac{x}{n^2} \right)^{n^2} \right) \equiv \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( e^x \right) \equiv \frac{x}{n} \equiv 0$